# rsync, optimize by moving files at the destination, instead of deleting and copying

Tags: linux, rsync, zfs

I want to do a Linux->Linux backup from server A to server B.

Users of server A often move multi-GB files and directories around, without changing them.

Will rsync (-avr --delete) spot that the destination already contains the multi-GB file in a different directory, and so avoid the network traffic?

If not, would using ZFS on servers A and B, and syncing with `zfs send` do the job?

Comment: [Unison file synchronizer](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) does this. It is designed for bidirectional sync, but has a `-force` option to mimic rsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `zfs send` can incrementally send differences between snapshots. Moving a file would manifest as a payload of a few bytes when doing an incremental `zfs send` between pre-existing snapshots on both sides.